# What would happen if a space whale crashed on earth?

Tags: politics, xenobiology

The universe is full with spaceborne creatures. One of them is the mighty space whale: 10 times bigger than a blue whale. This creature is dying and can't travel in space anymore. So this super organism dies and crashes on earth.

How would the political leaders around the earth react to this event?

EDIT : My space whale was an organic creature but can withstand radiation and heat. This means that my whale crashes on earth without taking much damage. It was trying to feed on earth minerals but died in the attempt.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "What would happen?"? You added the "politics" tag. Are you interested in the reaction of different countries? How much time do we have from the moment we realize a giant whale is coming towards us until it crash-lands? How fast is the creature? Is it completely like a normal whale (i.e. a magically enhanced giant whale) or do you have more specifics about your xeno-creature? Where will it hit the earth?

Comment: This creature is not a whale obviously.Is an organism that evolved to live in the void of space,Im interested about what would the world goverments do,Quarantine? Try to claim the whale? ETC ETC.

Comment: I am pretty sure the space-whale would be destroyed upon hitting earth. There wouldn't be much left if some organism was going through our atmosphere and hitting the ground. But we need to know more about your creature to give specific answers to your question: What is your space-whale made of? What damage can it sustain? What happens when it hits the earth? Are a few countries destroyed or is it just washed ashore for some unknown reason? Please edit your question to provide the info from your comment and some more info about your whale so that we know what kind of object we are talking about

Comment: Assuming it falls in the ocean, dies and sinks, I doubt anyone would ever notice it, unless it had been spotted when it was still in space.

Comment: @Secespitus My space whale was an organic creature but can sustand radiation and heat,So my whale crash without much damage.It was trying to feed on earth minerals but died in the attempt.

Comment: This starts to sound interesting. Please edit your answer to provide the information that you added in your comments above and elaborate them in more detail.

Comment: *This* would happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCsfHVM5x_I

Comment: US President would call it fake news :)

Comment: "How would these characters react" isn't worldbuilding, it's the plot of your story. That's for you to figure out.

Comment: @Alex Darkshine: Your whale may be able to withstand radiation and heat, but I doubt it's immune to gravity.  The result of it crashing would be something similar to Arizona's Meteor Crater :-)

Comment: While your whale can take normal space heat that doesn't mean it can take the fires of hitting an atmosphere.  Nothing we know how to build can take the heat on a sustained basis--spacecraft only survive the plunge because it's short.  They get through the fire before it bakes through their insulation.

Comment: There's also a big problem of strength.  A spacegoing creature is going to be built light.  When it hits the atmosphere I expect it will come apart.  I think you will end up with something like Chelyabinsk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the purpose of this answer, I'll assume a non-sentient organism roughly like a whale lands on Earth. Obviously not a tool-using species, no clothing, etc. The animal is large enough that there is no question of a prank, and different enough that investigation shows a non-Earth origin.

## We are not alone in the universe!

So far extraterrestrial life are theories and clues, not hard facts. Ordinary people might be exited if the news reports of possible life on Mars, but if the life is [microscopic, long dead, and not proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_on_Mars#ALH84001), the excitement won't last.  If there is a complex organism like the space whale, that makes other sentient species **appear** much more likely. When will they come visit? Should we look for them?

## Basic science

Scientists would get a chance to look at an extraterrestrial organism. There is enough to give thousands of scientists a slice. Does the space whale use something like DNA? If so, it is a double helix? Which acids? What is the propulsion system? Rocket engines? Lightsails? Something else, unexplained by present-day science?

## Political reactions

- Grab it and keep it under wraps. The advantages mentioned above are too valuable to just give parts away. Only carefully chosen scientists get a look and all reports are classified *top secret*.
- When was it detected, and what does that say? What if it had been a [mile-wide rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_avoidance) and not a 1,000-ton whale? Who voted for and against their latest funding request?

Answer (score 2):

(edited) Upon further consideration, it's quite unlikely that our style of biology would work for a space whale (carbon based with liquid water featuring prominently). I can't even imagine a made-up biology that would work in space. Tardigrades can "survive" but they dry out and suspend all life so maybe it'd be better described as coming back to life. Some of the challenges surrounding space biology: zero atmospheric pressure, super high radiative heat loss, no protection from solar and cosmic radiation, no free mass floating around to build biology mass, and the only free energy is light. Maybe they gestate in a mass and energy rich environment such as nebulae, but even solving the mass problem I can't imagine the biology.

Honestly the easiest path forward might be a multi-dimensional creature which somehow has access to an environment and materials that we're not aware of. Where does it get the mass and energy necessary to support life? From someplace we are not equipped to see or touch, (but maybe we can start looking there now that we know about it). How does it move across interstellar distances given the speed of light and the lack of free energy between solar systems? Maybe it's not always entirely present in our universe.

As for what the authorities would do with a thousand tons of alien biology, I would hope that samples would be made freely available for scientific study. There's no rational reason to maintain secrecy and openness really helps scientific progress by creating a distributed non-blocking system. Then again secrecy seems to be engrained in governments so perhaps the finders would try to keep it secret (good luck given the size)

Comment: Hi, the OP is interested in the political inclinations of a space-whale landing on earth. Currently the question is pretty unclear and OP has to edit the question to include this detail. Please read the comments on the question.